# JWPlayer iOS SDK automatically translating caption options

Tags: ios, jwplayer

I'm using JWPlayer iOS SDK version 3.21.1, but I've found that the embedded subtitle options are automatically translated. How can I prevent this happening?

Web version - correct:

[image]

iOS version - incorrect

[image]

Comment: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/ios-add-and-customize-captions
have you set correct labels `.label(“English”)` for your captions?

Comment: The captions are embedded in the stream itself, I have no control over it